# MSB3274 when compiling VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio

Anyone experiencing the below message before? Any advises would be much appreciated.

**Warning   MSB3274 The primary reference "xyz.dll" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets   2110**

Comment: When compiling what in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to reference a lib that was built for a newer .NET framework, whilst your project uses an older version. To fix this you could either:

- Change the version of your project to match the library's version. That is from 4.0 to 4.5. You can try setting it to the latest .NET framework version and it should work. If you are using Visual Studio for this, you'd right-click on the project in Solution Explorer, and then select latest in Properties > Application > Target framework
- Find an older version of the library and use that in your References
- Use NuGet package manager for dependencies management

I'd suggest updating your project to the latest version of .NET and also start using NuGet for your references.

Comment: updating to latest version of .NET may very likely break support for older operating systems, particularly XP.